# Execute a script as another user

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I have 6 scripts that I execute with PHP, unfortunately, I have to execute it as my default user.
I tried to execute it with PHP only but it doesn't work.

Do you know how to do this without a big security breach ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php as a command line utility by typing `php /path/to/script.php`

The PHP script will be excecuted by the user you are logged in to.

Comment: The script is executed frome a website so I am not logged in with an user

Comment: In that case you should supply more info in your question. For example: why do you need elevated permissions, for what operation do you need it. Might be you just need to set file permissions correctly. The question looks like you are talking about PHP shell execution, and not something webserver related

Comment: Also: PHP is not always used as a language to build websites, it is also a general-purpose programming language of some sorts. Not all people know this. Hence the confusion here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` to run a program as a different user.

Here is an example. I am `root` from the beginning (which you can see since `id` tells it) and execute the program `id` as the user `hashier`.

```
$
$ id
uid=0(root)
$ sudo -u hashier id
uid=501(hashier)
$
```

Comment: I don't understant what it does

Comment: _Exactly_ what you asked in your topic for, execute a program as a different user. I run "id" first and it shows that it runs as user root, then I run it with -u hashier and it shows that it runs as user hashier.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really what the OP was looking for, but to explain what the command above does:  id is a command that prints information about the user running the script.  `sudo -u <user> <command>` runs the command <command> as the user <user>.  So in the example above `sudo -u hashier id` will run the command `id` as the user `hashier` and the output in the example shows that he was logged in as root, ran id, which output root's information, then ran `sudo -u hashier id` and printed out the id information of the user hashier.